# EF Core runtime migrations fail on creating database

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-8.0

## Problem

On first startup of my application, i try to create the database or execute all pending migrations.
When the database doesn't exist yet, it creates the database and then throws an error before applying any migrations.

## Recreating

The versions of applications/packages:

```
SQL-server    Microsoft SQL Server 2022 - 16.0.4105.2 Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 
22.04.3 LTS) 

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 8.0.2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.2

dotnet-ef global tool 8.0.2
```

The code when my app starts:

```cs
using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
context.Database.Migrate();
```

Tried several times and sometimes I got a timeout exception but sometimes, the migrations went on for minutes (+10).

My SQL-user in the connectionstring has sysadmin rights.

The weird thing is that migrating using the dotnet-ef update commmand works perfectly:

```
PM> dotnet ef database update
```

## Expected behavior

I would assume that 'context.Database.Migrate();' does the same thing as 'dotnet ef database update': creating and migrating the targetted database.

Comment: so which error exactly does it show (complete in text form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was another process trying to access the database. I had NLog configured to log write its logs into a table of the same database. In the NLog.config, the throwsExceptions was set to false. By disabling the logs while database isn't created yet, the problem was solved.